# I'm getting 2 errors while running my postman script on a docker in GitLab. The same script is running fine through Postman and Newman

Tags: gitlab, postman, newman

I'm getting two errors as shown in the attached screenshot while trying to run my postman script (collection.json) on a docker in GitLab. The following are the details regarding the my system settings:

```
1. Newman Version: 4.1.0
2. OS details: Windows 7, 64 bit
3. Expected behaviour: I should get the Status code as 200 and my assertion should pass.
4. Command/script used to run Newman: newman run Generate_Access_Token.postman_collection.json --reporters cli, html --reporter-html-export report.html
I'm getting two errors as shown in the attached screenshot while trying to run my postman script (collection.json) on a docker in GitLab
```

Comment: You need to re-edit this question for anyone to provide any sort of answer. Using a github centric issue template is not how you ask questions on this platform.

Comment: It looks like a certificate issue, have you run that collection using Newman locally without the Docker image?

Comment: I mean, the error is in front of you about what the problem is - There is a certificate issue with the API that you're getting your token from. Not really sure what else to say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked for me by adding --insecure at the end of my run statement. The new statement looks like the below:

- newman run Generate_Access_Token.postman_collection.json --reporters cli, html --reporter-html-export report.html --insecure